# How to draw logarithmic function graph without irregularities

Tags: tikz-pgf

In this minimal working example, the graph of the natural logarithm function has a blemish between x = 0.5 and x = 0.6, no idea why... Does anyone know how to get rid of that and have a smooth graph?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (OR) at (0.00, 0.00);
\coordinate (LX) at (-1.00, 0.00); % left x
\coordinate (RX) at (8.00, 0.00); % right x
\coordinate (BY) at (0.00, -5.00); % bottom y
\coordinate (TY) at (0.00, 3.00); % top y
%
% axa 0x
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (LX) -- (RX);
\node[blue] at (7.8,-0.4) {\textbf{\textit{x}}};
%
% axa 0y
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (BY) -- (TY);
\node[right,blue] at (0.2, 2.8) {\textbf{\textit{ln x}}};
%
% ORIGIN
% 
\filldraw [red] (OR) circle(2pt);
\node[red] at (0.2,-0.3) {\textbf{\textit{0}}};
%
\draw[red,dotted,line width=0.75pt] (0.5, 0.0) -- (0.5, -1.0);
\draw[red,dotted,line width=0.75pt] (0.6, 0.0) -- (0.6, -1.0);
% graphic for LOGARITHM function
\draw[blue, line width=1.75pt, domain=0.005:7.00] plot[smooth](\x, {ln(\x)});
%\draw[blue, line width=1.75pt, domain=0.01:7.00] plot[smooth](\x, {ln(\x)});
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can force it to take more sample points

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (OR) at (0.00, 0.00);
\coordinate (LX) at (-1.00, 0.00); % left x
\coordinate (RX) at (8.00, 0.00); % right x
\coordinate (BY) at (0.00, -5.00); % bottom y
\coordinate (TY) at (0.00, 3.00); % top y
%
% axa 0x
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (LX) -- (RX);
\node[blue] at (7.8,-0.4) {\textbf{\textit{x}}};
%
% axa 0y
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (BY) -- (TY);
\node[right,blue] at (0.2, 2.8) {\textbf{\textit{ln x}}};
%
% ORIGIN
% 
\filldraw [red] (OR) circle(2pt);
\node[red] at (0.2,-0.3) {\textbf{\textit{0}}};
%
\draw[red,dotted,line width=0.75pt] (0.5, 0.0) -- (0.5, -1.0);
\draw[red,dotted,line width=0.75pt] (0.6, 0.0) -- (0.6, -1.0);
% graphic for LOGARITHM function
\draw[blue, line width=1.75pt, domain=0.005:7.00,samples=500] plot[smooth](\x, {ln(\x)});
%\draw[blue, line width=1.75pt, domain=0.01:7.00] plot[smooth](\x, {ln(\x)});
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm!! Generally speaking, what is the rule of thumb for the sample rate? How does one come up with a figure like 500, is it by trials or is there an algorithm for that?

Comment: @Diegis I guessed

Answer (score 3):

You are already loading `pgfplots` whcih was designed for this, why don't you use it? Your code will be mush simpler:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
clip=false
]
\addplot+[no marks,blue,line width=1pt,samples=150,domain=0.1:7] {ln(x)};
\draw[red,dotted,line width=0.75pt] (axis cs:0.5, 0.0) -- (axis cs:0.5, -1.0);
\draw[red,dotted,line width=0.75pt] (axis cs:0.6, 0.0) -- (axis cs:0.6, -1.0);
\node[label={[red]-45:0},fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt,circle] at (axis cs:0.02,0) {};
\node[right,blue] at (axis cs:0.2,1.8) {\textbf{\textit{ln x}}};
\node[below,blue] at (axis cs:7,-0.2) {\textbf{\textit{x}}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Truth of the matter is I do not know how to use \addplot, that is the problem. Is there a good tutorial for it somewhere? I just started with tikz... I do not even know to use \begin{axis}, I see it here used in a more understandable way for the first time!

Comment: @Diegis You have the [pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf); it's a comprehensive manual which includes lots of examples to help you get started with the package.